AWS TargetGroup running on port 80 as well as the dynamic port, how to remove port 80?
I am setting up an AWS CloudFormation stack that spins up an ECS cluster. It has an LB that routes traffic to TargetGroups on the cluster. The TaskDefinitions have HostPort:0 (dynamically assigned) and that works fine - the apps work, healthcheck works, all is good.
The TargetGroups have their dynamic ports (eg 35001 or something) that the apps are running on (healthy), but they also have port 80 that just sits there with "Unhealthy" status. I don't like that being open, nor do I like it showing unhealthy.
How do I get rid of the port 80 on the TargetGroups?
Note that my TargetGroup definitions do have Port: 80 defined because I don't know what else to do. I assume that is why the port 80 is showing up - but I don't want it. Setting to Port: 0 fails for TargetGroup definitions.
I have another old CF stack that is a similar setup and also has Port: 80 configured but the port is removed along the line somewhere (I assume on Task setup). But I can't figure out what configuration I need to change to make that work in my new stack. I don't see any significant differences between the Task or TargetGroup definitions. Any help is appreciated, thanks.
